# SEARCH_PROJECTION not working on Galaxy Note 3 Android

Tags: android, permissions, cursor, galaxy

I am using the following code to retrieve search queries from the browser, it works well with all other devices except Samsung Galaxy Note 3, the cursor returns empty i.e no search is retrieved.

```
Cursor mCur = mCtx.getContentResolver().query(Browser.SEARCHES_URI,
                Browser.SEARCHES_PROJECTION, null, null,
                Browser.SearchColumns.DATE + " DESC");
```

My manifest contains the required permissions:

READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS

Kindly let me know what can be wrong .